# Der Druck auf die Mietenden steigt und steigt. Warum "die Mietenden", aber nicht "die Mieter*innen"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammatical-number, gender-neutrality

the question is about the word "die Mietenden" in following sentence:

**Der Druck auf die Mietenden steigt und steigt**.

The sentence was found in M+W journal published by Swiss Mietverband.
In particular, I was looking for a plural from *der Mieter / die Mieterin*, the results being as follows: *die Mieter/-innen* (as per standard DE rules).

However, I can't grasp why exactly die Mietende was used in here, why didn't the authors use *die Mieter*innen*, for example? Could this word be used because of the style of the article (i.e. a Swiss-German word)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different ways to apply "gender neutrality" rules to a sentence or term. The participle form (*"Mietende"*)  has been around since at least the 1990s, the **innen*, *_innen* and *:innen* forms are much more recent and more blatantly advertising the cause. Different people prefer different forms, some also like variation.

Comment: So it was a choice of the author. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

> die Mieter/-innen (as per standard DE rules)

There are no such "standard DE rules". In fact there are only people who want to change german grammatical rules, because German has a [*generisches Maskulinum*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum): that means, i.e. "die Mechaniker" means mechanics of undefined (or various) gender and "der Mechaniker" is either a certain (male) mechanic or an abstract category (i.e. *der Beruf des Mechanikers*), whereas "die Mechaniker*innen*" means female mechanics only.

The problem with "Mieter/-innen" and similar constructions is that many of the 349 recognized genders known up to now are excluded and only "male" and "female" is recognized.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will definitely dig into the question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes for this correct answer.

Comment: Weil *es gibt ein generisches Maskulin* nicht die Antwort auf die Frage, warum da *Mietende* steht, ist.

Comment: @DavidVogt: OK, dann halt auf Deutsch: *es gibt ein generisches Maskulin [sic!]* war auch nicht die Antwort, sondern die Erläuterung zur Antwort, die im ersten Satz mit *There are no such "standard DE rules".* efolgte. Davor stand das Zitat aus der Frage, auf das sich die Antwort bezog. Ich erläutere das gerne für Dich nochmal explizit: die Frage in der Form, in der sie zum Antwortzeitpunkt gestellt war (mittlerweile wurde sie geändert), ging von falschen Voraussetzungen aus, nämlich dem Vorhandensein solcher Regeln.

Comment: “Der Mietende” ist maskulin, und auch generisches Maskulin. “Die Mietende” ist feminin. “Die Mietenden” ist Plural.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in at least two details. 1. _Mieter/-innen_ is currently the only orthographically correct contraction of _Mieter und Mieterinnen_, although _Mieter(innen)_ may be valid as well. 2. The very point of stylographic forms like _Mieter*innen_, _Mieter\_innen_ and _Mieter:innen_ is the inclusion of everyone in between and outside male and female designations, which _Mieter/-innen_ lacks.

Comment: Sure, there is a generic masculinum whereby _Mechaniker_ can refer to any member of the class that includes both female _Mechanikerinnen_ and male _Mechaniker._ However, there is also a non-generic masculinum whereby _Mechaniker_ refers to any member of the class of male _Mechaniker_ only. The problem with forms such as _Mechaniker_ or _Mieter_ is that you cannot know whether they are meant as generic masculinum or as non-generic masculinum.

Comment: Yes, there is a *generic* masculinum and a *non-generic* masculinum and you might be unable to tell which one. So? Language has many homonyms, if I were to say "Läufer" you won't know if I mean the carpet or the chess piece (or something else entirely). Does taht mean we have to rename one or all of them because of that ambiguity?